# Unable to query embedded document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have been studying how to use Mongodb, and have been stuck at querying data in embedded document for hours. I found example on Mongodb's website here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking

However, when I tried it with my own data such as

```
db.test.save({"name":"record", "items":[{"histPrices":[10,12],"name":"stuff"}]})
db.test.find({items.name:"stuff"})
```

It never finds anything, instead it is given me an error:
Fri Nov  2 14:24:09 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1

Anyone has any tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `histPrices.name`. But if you're using dot-notation, you should enclose the complex name in quotes.

```
> db.test.find({'items.name':"stuff"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("509416a3d78ed5021c34c12d"),
    "name" : "record",
    "items" : [
        {
            "histPrices" : [
                10,
                12
            ],
            "name" : "stuff"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oops, it was a typo when I made the post. I'll give the quotes a try.

Comment: if you use `items.name` for the original question, will it still work?